# Sample Capture Files to Test Password Cracking

Tags: linux, password-cracking, kali-linux

I was wondering if there are sample .cap files that can be downloaded to test password cracking with aircrack or or other tools for my homelab.

Thanks!

Comment: Based upon a quick and dirty Google search, I wasn't able to locate any sample .cap files that you could locally download and attempt to crack for testing purposes. I assume this was the case for you as well. I would recommend setting up a home-based lab in order to generate and practice cracking these yourself.

Comment: Yeah I looked everywhere and no luck lol. You would think that there would be some sort of capture file out there but guess not..

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why this got flagged as off-topic. Within the hash-cracking specialization, this is A) a perfectly legit question, and B) not tied to a specific product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options are a little constrained, but there are a few:

1. Capture your own - literally, the one from  your own setup that you control. This is the easiest way to guarantee that you know what the result should be, in order to validate your methodology. I would definitely start with this.
2. You could practice using [this one](https://hashcat.net/misc/example_hashes/hashcat.hccapx) (hccapx format, more on that below), from [the hashcat example hashes list](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes).
3. You could also participate in [the Stanev WPA cracking pool](https://wpa-sec.stanev.org/), and try some of the captures that you receive. However, this would be much less effective for practice purposes (since there's no guarantee that you'll be able to crack any of them).

Note also that the most robust and modern WPA capture format (IMO) is now [hccapx](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hccapx). You can convert to/from that format (and take advantage of other tools dedicated to this process) using ZerBea's [hcxtools](https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools).